# Fatal Error on controller in magento

Tags: php, magento

I am new in magento. here i have installed [this](http://urthemes.com/magento-photo-gallery-extension.html) an extension name as [igallery extension](http://urthemes.com/magento-photo-gallery-extension.html).

we can able to open **system >> configuration** and it works fine. but cant able to open  **i-Gallery >> Add i-Gallery** and **i-Gallery >> Manage i-Gallery**.

When i go this option i got error as below (**i-Gallery >> Add i-Gallery**)

```
"Fatal error: Call to a member function load() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\upgrade_doormore\app\code\community\My\Igallery\controllers\Adminhtml\BannerController.php on line 60"
```

getting blank page (**i-Gallery >> Manage i-Gallery**).

Comment: How exactly are you loading this gallery? (code and backend-admin-wise)

Comment: there is an option to add gallery via admin (i-Gallery >> Add i-Gallery) menu is navigate in admin panel

Comment: Hi Marius, Thanks for ur rply. "disable the compiler if enabled." it is works fine but another some functions are gone away in the site. that is another extenison funtions are getting errors in the site.